# Least squares fit, unknown intercerpt

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I have three data points through which I have to fit a straight line of the form Y=m*X+C. I want the line to have pre-determined slope 'm' but the constant'C' can change to get the least error while fitting using matlab. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What error metric? absolute difference?

Comment: The standard error. Sum (Ymeasured-Ypredicted).^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the math:

C= mean(Y)-m*mean(X)

assuming Y is the vector containing the y coordinates, and X the x coordinates.

Reference: http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit.html

Answer (score 0):

If you opt to use the Curve Fitting Toolbox the solution is as follows.

To start generate some data

```
m = 3;
x = (1:10).';
y = m*x + 2 + randn(size(x));
```

then select the model to fit and set the bounds for its coefficients

```
ft = fittype('poly1');
opts = fitoptions('Method', 'LinearLeastSquares');
opts.Lower = [m -Inf];
opts.Upper = [m  Inf];
```

finally call the fitting routine

```
[fitresult, gof] = fit(x, y, ft, opts);
```

The intercept is stored in `fitresult.p2`.